# CSS Textarea width is wrong also margin left and right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a fiddle to show something strange. I created a DIV 200px width and inside this DIV i inserted a textarea using CSS. Because it is a box div like the rest of the design I need the texarea to have 10px margin left and 10px margin right, so I edited the margins and set the width of textarea to 180 because if outer div is 200px and 10px padding left - 10px padding right I have 180px left to be used in textarea width

Here is the code I used:

CSS

```
#messenger {
    margin-left:10px;   margin-right:10px;    margin-top:10px;    margin-bottom:10px;
    width:180px;      height:64px;  overflow:auto;
    background:#ffffff;    font-size:11px;   font-weight:normal;   color:#333333;
    border:1px solid #666666; 
    padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:2px;
}

#outer {width:200px;background:#cccccc;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="outer">
<textarea name="message" id="messenger" form="chat" maxlength="100" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';">
Your message here
</textarea>
</div>
```

well it is looking pretty bad here is the demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/f3d1t223/

[image: And also a screenshot]

I really need it to have borders 1px too. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this one.

```css
#messenger {
    margin:10px;
    width:168px;      
    height:64px;  
    overflow:auto;
    background:#ffffff;    
    font-size:11px;   
    font-weight:normal;   
    color:#333333;
    border:1px solid #666666; 
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-top:2px;
}

#outer {width:200px;background:#cccccc;}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
<textarea name="message" id="messenger" form="chat" maxlength="100" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';">
Your message here
</textarea>
</div>
```

acording to your code you have padding and border size also so need to reduce those values from the width of the textarea.

Comment: Just reducing the size of 180px minus borders and margins and paddings? Will this work on all browsers ?

Comment: yes why not i'm not specify any browser specific rules. just this is simple css. this code should support for all browsers .. test it ..

Answer (score 1):

```
/*Add*/
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/svansoeren/yaj10txk/13/

Answer (score 0):

Add on your textarea this code:

```
/*Add*/
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
resize: vertical;
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/f3d1t223/3/)

Comment: I didn't know that this could solve this problem, please explain.

Comment: Hehehe same question odedta

Comment: But you know what? I tried it just for fun on the demo fiddle and it works. The question is why and if it will work on all browsers

Comment: look on this link guys https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/   Yes this work on all browsers :)